# How to get optional chaining working in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, optional-chaining

Looks like optional chaining [has landed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33294). [Here's an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeBYAUDXMAeAXDAIzYC+22oksARgIYBOKMA2giALoDcVWNCCAA2AUwB0wkAHMAFIyZsADFwD84-AEoeQA)

What I can't figure out is how to get TS to compile it properly. I'm not getting any syntax errors in my project, but this:

```
let imageFileId = (await db.query(sql`select id from image_files where sha256=${sha256}`))[0]?.id;
```

Is being output as:

```
let imageFileId = (await db.query(mysql3_1.sql `select id from image_files where sha256=${sha256}`))[0]?.id;
```

Which won't run until we get native support in Node.

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "importHelpers": false,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": ["es2018"],
        "skipLibCheck": false,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "target": "esnext",
        "declaration": false,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["src/*"]
        },
        "noEmit": false
    },
    "files": [
        "src/index"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Is there some other option I need to enable to compile the `?.` operator?

Please note I'm *not* using Babel and I don't want to bring it into the picture.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is you are targeting `esnext` this will tell the compiler to output all language features as is without any transpilation.  Set the language to es2020 (or below) and `?.` and `??` will get transpiled to compatible code:

```
(async function () {
    let imageFileId = (await db.query(sql`select id from image_files where sha256=${sha256}`))[0]?.id;
})()
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=7&ssl=3&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/BQQwzgngdgxgBAMwK6wC4EsD2U7AJRwDeAUHGXADYCmqc6AtiAOZUBi61AkgCZwC8uEAHcQ6WtwBGAOgCOSKgCcIwMDIoADMFWoxa6XggWZ6dRiwD6CDlTBwhAC0VU4YeyABMAVgBsfACSErh4+AL7qeHgA2gAMALoA-FL6ANzEIXj4QA)

There is no fine-grained control over which language features get transpiled and which don't do you have to pick a version as a whole unfortunately,

Comment: Problem with that is that I'm also using BigInts which have been supported by node for awhile now :-( "TS2737: BigInt literals are not available when targeting lower than ESNext"

Comment: @mpen  I was just editing my answer to address that. There unfortunately is no way to control which specific language features get compiled and which don't

Comment: @mpen Babel is better at supporting pick and choose with regard to language features..

Comment: I'm having the same problem again after upgrading to **TypeScript 3.8**. I think you should actually target `es2019` in order to "polyfill" optional chaining.

Comment: @icl7126 is right. For **TS 3.8.3** you have to set `ES2019` as a target

Comment: setting `target: ES2019` is still true for **TS 3.9.5**

Comment: @I'llEatMyHat changed the answer to reflect that any version below es2020 will work, it's just esnext that preserves the original operators.

Comment: I mean that ES2020 doesn't work for me though. Only ES2019 and below does.
ES2020 results in the error `You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.`

Comment: It seems to be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972341/how-to-make-webpack-accept-optional-chaining-without-babel) which refers to a [webpack dependency's PR](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/pull/891)

Answer (score 5):

Well, I didn't want to use Babel because then I'd have to figure out how to replace `ts-node`. There's a bunch of outdated docs out there referring to old Babel packages, but these instructions should work as of Nov 2019:

Add a `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env",{"targets": {"node": "current"}}],
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-bigint"
    ]
}
```

Add these deps:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-bigint": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.7.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.5",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  }
```

Execute your code with:

```
node_modules/.bin/babel-node --extensions ".ts" src/index.ts
```

The `--extensions ".ts"` is very important, even though you're explicitly trying to execute a .ts file, it won't transpile it w/out that.

I like to use GNU Make instead of package.json scripts:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules
.SUFFIXES:
NM := node_modules/.bin
.PHONY: build start dev clean test publish

## commands
########################################

__default:
    $(error Please specify a target)

build: build-types build-js dist/package.json

build-types: node_modules/.yarn-integrity
    $(NM)/tsc --emitDeclarationOnly

build-js: node_modules/.yarn-integrity
    $(NM)/babel src --out-dir dist --extensions ".ts" --source-maps inline

run: node_modules/.yarn-integrity
    $(NM)/babel-node --extensions ".ts" src/index.ts

check: node_modules/.yarn-integrity
    $(NM)/tsc --noEmit

dist:
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    rm -rf node_modules dist yarn-error.log

dist/package.json: package.json | dist
    jq 'del(.private, .devDependencies, .scripts, .eslintConfig, .babel)' $< > $@

## files
########################################

node_modules/.yarn-integrity: yarn.lock
    @yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production=false --check-files
    @touch -mr $@ $<

yarn.lock: package.json
    @yarn check --integrity
    @touch -mr $@ $<
```

Or just copy from [Microsoft's TypeScript Babel Starter](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter).