# How to make webpack accept optional chaining without babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, optional-chaining

Scenario:

- We're using webpack 4 to create a bundle from our Javascript sources.
- We're **not** using Babel because we're authoring only for a single platform (latest Chrome), and we're only using features directly available in Chrome, thus no transpiling is required.

The plus side of this is a *smaller bundle*, and *much faster turnaround times* while developing.

Now we would like to start using the [stage 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/) [optional chaining feature](https://tc39.es/proposal-optional-chaining/#top) which [can be enabled in Chrome using a flag](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining).

I've tried to google this, and all I was able to find is that [babel has a plugin for this](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining).

**Question: Is there any way to make webpack accept this syntax while omitting babel?**

Here's what webpack currently reports:

```
ERROR in ./src/js/components/custom-select.js 245:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (245:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|      */
|     focus() {
>         this.input?.focus();
|         return this;
|     }
 @ ./src/js/components/components.js 16:0-49 16:0-49
```

Comment: Relevant issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10216

Comment: The parser webpack uses only implements stage 4 features, optional chaining is still afaik stage 3. It seems like they're not interested in supporting this specific usecase (stage 3 features with no downgrading)

Comment: @Klaycon Optional chaining **is** stage 4. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/

Comment: Quite right, my apologies. Acorn (the parser used by webpack) has an open pull request for optional chaining here: https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/pull/891

Comment: @Klaycon It seems you can make that an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relating to @Klaycon's answer, [Acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) released today a [new version](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/releases/tag/7.3.0) that supports optional chaining.
As soon as Webpack reflects the change on their side- using optional chaining with webpack shouldn't be a problem anymore.

Comment: The issue for this is being tracked here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10227

Answer (score 8):

According to [this similar issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10216), webpack relies on the parser [Acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) and thus presumably needs Acorn to support optional chaining first. Acorn has an open pull request [here](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/pull/891) for optional chaining, but in the meantime, a "solution" suggested by a user in the first issue is to disable parsing on the files you need optional using [module.noParse](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#modulenoparse) until such a time that Acorn and webpack support the feature.

**Update:** Optional chaining is now supported in Acorn as of [v7.3.0](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/releases/tag/7.3.0), and according to [this webpack issue comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10227#issuecomment-642734920), it sounds like they don't expect webpack to support it until webpack 5 releases. The progress to webpack 5 can be tracked [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/projects/5).

Comment: Unfortunately: *Ignored files should not have calls to import, require, define or any other importing mechanism.* We do have `import`s, of course, so the only thing I can do at this point is wait for that pull request to be merged, then wait until webpack upgrades to that new version of acorn.

Answer (score 5):

It occurs that optional chaining won't be supported by Webpack 4 alone, however, it is already supported in Webpack 5, so if it's possible the best course of action would be to [upgrade to Webpack 5](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/).

Otherwise if you can't update to Webpack 5, you should use Babel ([@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining)) or TypeScript compiler (`target` at most `ES2019`) for optional chaining transpilation.

Comment: I think you meant `es2019`

Comment: @MilanVelebit thank you for noticing the typo! Feel free to edit other people answers if you find issues like that ;)