# Nullcheck on nullable Types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript, with the following code interface definition.

```
export Interface Response {
  content?: {
    // ...
  }
}

let response: Response | null = something();
```

How to access content without doing null checks, which i assume is not at all the best approach.

```
if (response != null) {
  if (response.content != null) {
    content = (response.content as MyContent);
  }
}
```

Comment: `response?.content?.something`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get optional chaining working in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58725711/how-to-get-optional-chaining-working-in-typescript)

Comment: If i add ?. i get TS1109 Expression expected

Comment: Sounds like your version of TS is too low.

Comment: im on version 3.0.3 of typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running version `3.0.x` version of typescript, this does not support the [Safe Navigation Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator).

Updating typescript made it possible to do something similar to.

```
response?.content?.something
```

Answer (score 0):

content = response?.content == null ? null : response.content as MyContent;