# React JS: syntax error unexpected token '?.'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Iam getting this error on all of my .js files

```
Syntax error: BreadCrumb.js: Unexpected token (114:43)

  112 |         v={visible}
  113 |         b={barrs}
> 114 |         nameBartagemAttxl={currentBartagem?.Name || ""}
      |                                            ^
  117 |       />
```

I've tried many config on my tsconfig.json but nothing works...

My guessing is that all the .js files arent recognizing a more recent version of the 'ES'

Any ideias?

this is my tsconfig.json configuration file at the moment

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "suppressExcessPropertyErrors": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.jsx",
  ]
}
```

this is my version TypeScript:
`"typescript": "3.7.2"`

Comment: You may need to update the `target` config in tsconfig to be `es2020`

Comment: You're using TS syntax in JS files

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković arent there a way to .js files reconize the versions of es6 or newer?

Comment: This is because currentBartagem is not an object with the property Name. Most likely it is a different variable type.

Comment: @SteveTomlin the property is just fine, if I remove the '?.' operator it work, but i need that operator there and all the other files

Comment: Then again it might be because you need to include equivalent of - "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining in your typescript config. - See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58725711/how-to-get-optional-chaining-working-in-typescript. "Set the language to es2020 (or below) and ?. and ?? will get transpiled to compatible code:"

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković optional operator is not only-TS construct. It is supported by JS too (by newer versions).

Comment: @SteveTomlin thanks!! installing babel did the trick!